# Timestamp from one df between 2 timestamps from another df

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following 2 df's:

```
# -- create a df1 
list_columns = ['time', 'code', 'age']
list_data = [
    ['2019-11-18 10:33:53', 'a1', 10],
    ['2019-11-18 11:33:56', 'a2', 15],
    ['2019-11-18 12:33:58', 'a4', 6],
    ['2019-11-18 13:45:04', 'a5', 3]
    ]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list_columns, data=list_data)
```

and

```
# -- create a df2
list_columns = ['start_time','end_time','name', 'country']
list_data = [
    ['2019-11-18 10:31:53','2019-11-18 10:35:53' ,'nick', 'germany'],
    ['2019-11-18 11:32:53','2019-11-18 11:35:53', 'joe', 'usa'],
    ['2019-11-18 12:33:58', '2019-11-18 12:35:58','smith', 'california'],
    ['2019-11-18 13:42:04','2019-11-18 13:47:04', 'sam', 'france']
    ]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list_columns, data=list_data)
df1.head()
```

Don't know if possible in pandas but if **time** from df1 is between **start_time** and **end_time** from df2, in df1 i would like to add after **age** the columns **name** and **country** from df2. Sort of a join.

With dates I would use a mask like this:

```
mask = (df1['time'] > df2s['start_time]) & (df1['time'] <= df2s['end_time])
df1 = df1.loc[mask]
```

But here I am dealing with timestamps and I need to take in consideration the hh:mm. Can you give me a hint on how I can achieve my goal?

Comment: cross merge and filter.

Comment: Is each row in `df1` corresponded with a row in `df2` ? In other words, you want to check your time condition for any row in df1 with all rows in df2 or it's only first row from d1 with first row from df2, second row with second row and so on ?

Comment: no. in df 1 I could have 20 rows that are between start_time and end_time from df2. If the condition is correct in df 1 i want to add the name and country columns from df2

Comment: I tried also this: if (df_w['Timestamp'] > df_materials['TRC_START_TIME']) & (df_w['Timestamp'] <= df_materials['TRC_END_TIME']):
    df_w['TRC_MAT_SAP_CODE'] = df_materials['TRC_MAT_SAP_CODE']    but I get ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Answer (score 1):

Your `start_time` and `end_time` intervals seem to overlaps. Do you expect multiple matches? You can do a cross merge like this:

```
(df1.assign(tmp=1)
    .merge(df2.assign(tmp=1), on='tmp', how='left')
    .query('start_time <= time <= end_time')
    .drop(['start_time', 'end_time'], axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
                  time code  age  tmp   name     country
0  2019-11-18 10:33:53   a1   10    1   nick     germany
5  2019-11-18 11:33:56   a2   15    1    joe         usa
10 2019-11-18 12:33:58   a4    6    1  smith  california
15 2019-11-18 13:45:04   a5    3    1    sam      france
```